# SQL-Server - Access Linked Server (Cannot initialize the data source object)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, error-handling, odbc, linked-server

I am currently configuring a linked server connection between Microsoft SQL-Server and a Microsoft Access database in our network. To make things easy, I saved the Access db locally and tried to configure the linked server.

First I created a system-DSN named "BADEN32" (32 bit)
This DSN refers to my Access database (located C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Baden.accdb)
For this DSN, I used the Microsoft Access Driver (.mdb .accdb)

When I try to create a new linked server, I keep getting the following error: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "BADEN32"
I have already checked the MSDASQL provider if allow inprocess was true, but it was.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You're linking to the SQL server from the Access Database?  You would need to set up an ODBC connection to the SQL server and test it. Once it is working, go to the Access Database, External Data Tab, then ODBC Database to set up.

If this isn't what you mean, could I get more information?

Comment: Because we sometimes have to change tables, I am trying to set up a connection where I pull in the tables and data from Access to SQL server. When creating linked tables, I won't be able to edit the columns and tables. This is my biggest concern